# Finding Transition Probabilities using Metropolis Hastings

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, markov-chains

[image]

I want to find the $4$x$4$ Probability Transition Matrix under the temperature parameter T=2 of Metropolis Hastings. 
I know that, if x and y are neighbors,

$p(x,y) =$   $$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{1}{N} & \quad \Delta E(x,y) \leq 0 \\
            \frac{1}{N}*e^{-\Delta \frac{E(x,y)}{T}} & \quad \Delta E(x,y) > 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

but I'm not sure what N represents.

If I want, say, $p(1,2)$, I know that the probability is $\frac{1}{N}$ because the change in energy is negative, but I'm not sure what $N$ is and my textbook does not specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$N$ is the number of neighbours. You select one of the $N$ neighbours uniformly, with equal probability $\frac1N$, and then you move to that neighbour with probability $1$ if it has lower energy, and with probability given by the exponential factor if it has higher energy.